# In java 9 how to send JSON data through websocket

Tags: java, java-9

In Java 9 new features are added and one of them is WebSocket, I have found articles related to sending text(string)/binary messages only. So, how to send JSON data over websocket using Java 9.

Comment: JSON is just text format, so same rules apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can treat JSON similar to text. just deserialize  it and send it as a plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Write your data in `StringWriter`

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(writer, object);
    String jsonText = writer.toString;
```

Now you have a String with your JSON.